# sklearn module not found when using VSCode, but works fine in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, anaconda

I have looked at several questions and tried their respective answers, but I cannot seem to understand why VSCode is unable to find the sklearn module.

I use a virtual conda environment called `ftds`, in which I have scikit-learn successfully show up when I run `conda list`. In jupyter notebook, I use the same `ftds` environment and sklearn works fine. In VSCode, I keep getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'` error message.

I ensure I have activated my conda environment using `conda activate ftds` prior to running my code. I also ensure that scikit-learn was successfully installed into the `ftds` environment using conda. I have the latest version, which is `version 1.1.1` at the time of this question.

For further information, I am using MacOS Monterey (Version 12.5). Has anyone had the same issue? I am only able to find those who had issues with jupyter notebook, which is the opposite of my problem.

I have already selected the `ftds` environment as the python interpreter in VSCode. Other packages like pandas, numpy, etc. are all functioning as normal.

Comment: Is there any progress on the issue?

Comment: @JialeDu, so I did the same as you said but still did not get sklearn to run. I did find that sklearn successfully imports if I use a .ipynb file, but does not import correctly when I use a .py file. Both files use the same conda environment, which was successfully activated. The module is confirmed to be in the environment `ftds` as well. But otherwise, nothing else has changed

Comment: sorry my answer didn't work. Could you post your detailed error message? And your file structure, screenshot of the error interface.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue: the python library name for **sklearn** is [**scikit-learn**](https://scikit-learn.org)

Installing **scikit-learn** with `pip install scikit-learn`.

I saw that after typing `pip show sklearn` it says that the package is deprecated in favor of [**scikit-learn**](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/). So i tried installing that after which `sklearn` worked with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be a very simple answer, but can you check that the correct interpreter (in your case "ftds") is selected at the bottom right in VSCode?

I sometimes have exactly the same problem in my own work and I realize that most of the time I forget to check it.

[image]

Comment: forgot to include that I have indeed selected the right interpreter, but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have installed the **sklearn** package, but you still get the `ModuleNotFoundError` error message. In most cases you must not choose the corresponding interpreter. Or your **sklearn** package is not installed in the current python environment.

Please use the `pip show sklearn` command to view the installation information of **sklearn**. Make sure to choose the correct interpreter.
Or activate the environment you want to use and install the **sklearn** package using the `pip install sklearn` command.